# SQL Server table design and using SqlBulkCopy to insert data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2014, sqlbulkcopy

I just need a suggestion on making the best use of `SqlBulkCopy`.

Say I have a table as shown below

```
    Type BidNumber HQregion Services PrimaryExec Value
    --------------------------------------------------
          22        USA      Some     None         33
          24        Europe   None     Delta        44
    SL    22        USA      Some     Tango        39
    GV    44        Mexico   Delta    Charlie      33
    Time  22        India    Charlie  None         33
```

There can be say about 100k entries with empty `Type` column 100k with `SL` with some same data points as empty but some different and I am using `SqlBulkCopy` to copy data from Excel files into this table.

I was wondering if I should break the table into multiple tables which have the same exact columns but differentiate based on the type so one table for say `MainData`, another for `SLData` and `GVData` and then use `SqlBulkCopy` to just insert data into specific tables. Is that a bad design with multiple tables when only one column data is different and is that going to be any efficient when using bulk copy since I have to delete the data before inserting and it's a nightly process.

So the final structure would be:

Main Table

```
BidNumber HQregion Services PrimaryExec Value
```

SL Table

```
BidNumber HQregion Services PrimaryExec Value
```

GV Table

```
BidNumber HQregion Services PrimaryExec Value
```

Time Table

```
BidNumber HQregion Services PrimaryExec Value
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overcomplicate things. 100k is small for sql bulk copy. Like tiny. It is a size I would expect to upload in a second or so.

Answer (score 0):

If for future reasons of increasing size you would like to divide the excels, I would suggest you to keep the excel as it is and bulk copy the complete data into staging table and then multicast the specific filtered data to corresponding tables.